# how to make ranking of value in oracle

Tags: oracle, ranking

I have table : tb_user.

```
id|name|value
10|boy|500
20|Ony|200
10|boy|500
```

When I execute the following query:

```
Select id,name,sum(value) as grant_total from tb_user group by id,name
```

the result is:

```
id|name|grant_total
10|boy |1000
20|Ony |200
```

I want to add 1 column --> ranking

```
id|name|grant_total|ranking
10|boy |1000       |1
20|Ony |200        |2
```

how to make ranking?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Select id,name,sum(value) as grant_total, rownum as ranking from tb_user group by id,name
```

Comment: If you use `ROWNUM` here you will get an error: `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`

Answer (score 0):

You could use **ROWNUM** and a subquery to first order the rows:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 10 ID, 'boy' NAME, 1000 grand_total FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 20, 'Ony', 200 grand_total from dual
  4  )
  5  SELECT t.*,
  6    rownum ranking
  7  FROM
  8    ( SELECT * FROM DATA ORDER BY grand_total DESC
  9    ) t
 10  /

        ID NAM GRAND_TOTAL    RANKING
---------- --- ----------- ----------
        10 boy        1000          1
        20 Ony         200          2

SQL>
```

Or,

You could use the **Analytic functions**:

For example,

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 10 ID, 'boy' NAME, 1000 grand_total FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 20, 'Ony', 200 grand_total from dual
  4  )
  5  SELECT t.*, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY grand_total DESC) ranking FROM DATA t;

        ID NAM GRAND_TOTAL    RANKING
---------- --- ----------- ----------
        10 boy        1000          1
        20 Ony         200          2

SQL>
```

Depending on the requirement, you need to use:

1. ROW_NUMBER
2. RANK
3. DENSE_RANK

Let's see an example,

```
SQL> SELECT empno, ename, sal FROM emp;

     EMPNO ENAME             SAL
---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH             800
      7499 ALLEN            1600
      7521 WARD             1250
      7566 JONES            2975
      7654 MARTIN           1250
      7698 BLAKE            2850
      7782 CLARK            2450
      7788 SCOTT            3000
      7839 KING             5000
      7844 TURNER           1500
      7876 ADAMS            1100
      7900 JAMES             950
      7902 FORD             3000
      7934 MILLER           1300

14 rows selected.

SQL> SELECT empno,
  2    ename,
  3    sal,
  4    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sal) rnum,
  5    RANK() OVER(ORDER BY sal DESC) rank,
  6    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY sal) drank
  7  FROM emp
  8  ORDER BY empno
  9  /

     EMPNO ENAME             SAL       RNUM       RANK      DRANK
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH             800          1         14          1
      7499 ALLEN            1600          8          7          7
      7521 WARD             1250          4         10          4
      7566 JONES            2975         11          4         10
      7654 MARTIN           1250          5         10          4
      7698 BLAKE            2850         10          5          9
      7782 CLARK            2450          9          6          8
      7788 SCOTT            3000         12          2         11
      7839 KING             5000         14          1         12
      7844 TURNER           1500          7          8          6
      7876 ADAMS            1100          3         12          3
      7900 JAMES             950          2         13          2
      7902 FORD             3000         13          2         11
      7934 MILLER           1300          6          9          5

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function (or `RANK()` if you want to rank ties equally):

```
SELECT id, name, SUM(value) AS grand_total
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY SUM(value) DESC ) AS ranking
  FROM tb_user
 GROUP BY id, name
 ORDER BY ranking;
```